# Query exibindo menos resultado do que realmente existe na exportação

Tags: php

Montei uma `query` com uma lista resultante de uma seleção de `checkbox` efetuada pelo usuário, a lista está com os valores corretos, conforme selecionados, mas ao verificar o conteúdo do resultado após consulta no `banco de dados` sempre me é exibido um registro a menos.

A minha lista está sendo montada assim:

```
// LISTA
$colname_rcCandidato = "-1";
if (isset($_GET['list'])) {
  $colname_rcCandidato = $_GET['list'];
}
```

A minha pesquisa está assim utilizando a lista

```
mysql_select_db($database_pcon, $pcon);
$query_rcLista = sprintf("SELECT   ongAtleta.IdAtleta, 
                                       ongAtleta.Nome, 
                                       ongEscola.Nome AS NomeEscola, 
                                       ongEscola.Municipio,
                                       ongAtleta.ProfResposavel
                                 FROM  ongAtleta
                                 INNER JOIN ongFichaEscolar ON ( ongAtleta.IdAtleta = ongFichaEscolar.IdAtleta ) 
                                 INNER JOIN ongEscola ON ( ongFichaEscolar.IdEscola = ongEscola.IdEscola ) 
                                 WHERE ongAtleta.IdAtleta IN (%s)", GetSQLValueString($colname_rcCandidato, "string"));
$rcLista = mysql_query($query_rcLista, $pcon) or die(mysql_error());
$row_rcLista = mysql_fetch_assoc($rcLista);
$linhas = mysql_num_rows($rcLista);
```

Minha exportação está assim, estou utilizando a `classe` `PHPExcel`:

```
if ($linhas > 0) {

    // Incluimos a classe PHPExcel
    include  '../_comp/externos/classes/PHPExcel.php';

    // Instanciamos a classe
    $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

    // Inicializando variável
    $rowCount = 1; 

    do {

        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A'.$rowCount, removeAcentos($row_rcLista['Nome'])); 
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('B'.$rowCount, removeAcentos($row_rcLista['NomeEscola'])); 
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('C'.$rowCount, removeAcentos($row_rcLista['ProfResposavel'])); 
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('D'.$rowCount, removeAcentos($row_rcLista['Municipio'])); 

        // Incrementando variável
        $rowCount++;    

    } while($row_rcLista = mysql_fetch_assoc($rcLista));

    // Nome da Planilha
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('AlunoEscola');

    // Efetua Download
    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="RelacaoAlunoEscola.xls"');
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
    // Se for o IE9, isso talvez seja necessário
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=1');

    // Salvando o Arquivo
    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');

    // Salva diretamente no output
    $objWriter->save('php://output'); 

    exit;

}
```

No exemplo que estou postando em uma imagem, são selecionados 4 registros e na exportação me são apresentados somente 3.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Pode ser um erro de formatação na celula, da um `f2` nela e veja se tem algo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Baseado rigidamente nos detalhes da pergunta o problema parece ser o `do-while`, `$row_rcLista` só vai ter um valor após a chamada de `mysql_fetch_assoc()` que é feita no final ou seja um linha em branco é adicionada. Mude o `do-while` para um `while`simples.

```
do {
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A'.$rowCount, removeAcentos($row_rcLista['Nome']));
    //código omitido 

    $rowCount++;    

} while($row_rcLista = mysql_fetch_assoc($rcLista)); // <---- atribuição
```

Solução:

```
while($row_rcLista = mysql_fetch_assoc($rcLista){
   $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A'.$rowCount, removeAcentos($row_rcLista['Nome'])); 
   //código omitido
   $rowCount++;  
}
```

Comment: Olá @rray, muito obrigado pela excelente dica, resolvi o problema.

Comment: @adventistapr qual era o real problema?

Comment: Olá @rray, me desculpe em demorar tanto para responder, a resposta é exatamente o que você postou:
"$row_rcLista só vai ter um valor após a chamada de mysql_fetch_assoc()"

Comment: @adventistapr legal bom que resolveu :)